# Flatten Dictionary with a List and return Custom IEnumerable

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a following data structure:

```
Dictionary<int, List<Home>> localDictionary;

Dictionary key here is the CityId of int type

public class Home
{
   public int Id;
   public string Address;
   public string Color;
}

//Following is the Output entity:

public class HomeOutput
{
   public int CityId;
   public int Id;
   public string Address;
   public string Color;
}
```

Final Result in the form of the collection of `HomeOutput` type will require flattening of the structure, since for every city, it needs to iterate over home list and fill the `HomeOutput` object

I can do it easily using the `foreach` loop by first iterating over keys then `List<Home>` and adding all the details to the `HomeOutput` collection, but not able to get the correct answer using Linq `SelectMany`, following is what I have tried:

```
List<HomeOutput> homeOutputList =
    localDictionary.SelectMany(
        x => x.Value.SelectMany<Home, HomeOutput>(
            y => new HomeOutput()
            {
                CityId = x.Key,
                Id = y.Id,
                Address = y.Address,
                Color = y.Color
            }))
        .ToList();
```

Error is I am trying to convert `HomeOutput` to `IEnumerable<HomeOutput>`, but what shall I modify to ensure that I can get the collection with correct result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe your `LINQ` might be slightly off. This should work.

```
List<HomeOutput> homeOutputList =
    localDictionary.SelectMany(
        x => x.Value.Select(
            y => new HomeOutput()
            {
                CityId = x.Key,
                Id = y.Id,
                Address = y.Address,
                Color = y.Color
            }))
        .ToList();
```

Comment: Oh that works like a breeze, thanks, it was a pestering mistake on my end, which I was trying to work around for an hour now :)